# SQL Statement - Using Count() & Sum() - and sorting

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I was trying to think of the best title for this one. I have a very complex query (using traditional ASP and SQL server) and I am going to make it more simple for example purposes.

This is for report.asp

```
SQL = "select EMPL.employeeName, " & _
      "COUNT(BUSINESS.ID) AS theTotal, " & _
      "COUNT(CASE WHEN BUSINESS.ID IS NULL THEN 1 END) as unTouched " & _
      "FROM EMPL Inner Join BUSINESS " & _
      "WHERE EMPL.STATUS = 1 " & _
      "GROUP BY EMPL.employeeName " & _
      "ORDER BY " & theOrder
```

Down in the HTML part I have a table that looks something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th><a href="report.asp?sort=1">Employee</th>
      <th><a href="report.asp?sort=2">Total</th>
      <th><a href="report.asp?sort=3">Untouched</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><%=RS("employeeName")%></td>
      <td><%=RS("theTotal")%></td>
      <td><%=RS("unTouched")%></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Finally at the top of the page I have a select case for the order by clause that looks like this:

```
theOrder = request.querystring("sort")

SELECT CASE theOrder
   CASE 1
      theOrder = "EMPL.employeeName"
   CASE 2
      theOrder = "theTotal, EMPL.employeeName"
   CASE 3
      theOrder = "unTouched, EMPL.employeeName"
   CASE ELSE
      theOrder = "EMPL.employeeName"
END SELECT
```

Everything works fine as intended. Now, I want to add a column at the end that figures up (theTotal - unTouched).

So I add this down in the loop code before the table rows:

```
do while not RS.eof

   TheDIfference = RS("theTotal") - RS("unTouched")

...
```

I add my table header for "Difference" and the new row that displays the subtraction and everything comes out perfect.

Here is the problem. I want to be able to sort by that column as well just like the other 2 columns. So I tried to add a line to my select statement that said:

```
SUM(theTotal - unTouched) AS theDifference
```

That didn't work so then I spelled it all out:

```
SUM(COUNT(BUSINESS.ID)- COUNT(CASE WHEN BUSINESS.ID IS NULL THEN 1 END)) AS theDifference
```

That didnt work either.

So is there a correct way to include that in the select statement so that I can do an orderby or a work around where I don't have to put it inside the statement itself?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: entire real query:

```
SQL = "SELECT E.[theTotal], E.[unTouched], (E.[theTotal] - E.[unTouched]) [theDifference] " & _
            "FROM ( " & _
            "SELECT EMPL.EMPLDesc, EMPL.EMPLID, EMPL.EMPLSalesmanID, COUNT(BLXF.BLXFBSNSID) AS theTotal, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' THEN 1 END) AS totalChamber, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' THEN 1 END) AS totalCity, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%' THEN 1 END) AS MulCnt, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%') THEN 1 END) AS MulCntChamber, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%') THEN 1 END) AS MulCntCity, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%' AND BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS MulCntChamberUN, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%' AND BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS MulCntCityUN, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%' THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCnt, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%') THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCntChamber, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%') THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCntCity, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%' AND BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCntChamberUN, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%' AND BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCntCityUN, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL THEN 1 END) as unTouched, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL AND RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p') THEN 1 END) as unTouchedChamber, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL AND RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c') THEN 1 END) as unTouchedCity, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%') THEN 1 END) as unTouchedMul, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%') THEN 1 END) as unTouchedNonMul, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%' THEN 1 END) as reRunCnt, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%' AND BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) as reRunCntUN, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%') THEN 1 END) AS reRunCntChamber, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%') THEN 1 END) AS reRunCntCity, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%' AND BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS reRunCntChamberUN, " & _
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%' AND BLXF.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS reRunCntCityUN " & _
          "FROM BLXF INNER JOIN LIST ON BLXF.BLXFLISTID = LIST.LISTID " & _
          "INNER JOIN BSST ON BLXF.BLXFBSSTID = BSST.BSSTID " & _
          "INNER JOIN EMPL ON LIST.LISTEMPLID = EMPL.EMPLID " & _
          "INNER JOIN PROJ ON LIST.LISTPROJID = PROJ.PROJID " & _
          "WHERE (LIST.LISTAvailable = 1) AND (BSST.BSSTTerminalInd = 0) AND (PROJ.PROJPJSTID = 2) AND (EMPL.EMPLStatus = 'y') " & _
          "GROUP BY EMPL.EMPLDesc, EMPL.EMPLID, EMPL.EMPLSalesmanID " & _
          ") E " & _
          "ORDER BY " & theOrderBy
```

UPDATED QUERY 2:

```
SQL = "SELECT E.[theTotal], E.[unTouched], (E.[theTotal] - E.[unTouched]) [theDifference] " & _
        "FROM ( " & _
        "SELECT E.EMPLDesc, E.EMPLID, E.EMPLSalesmanID, COUNT(B.BLXFBSNSID) AS theTotal, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' THEN 1 END) AS totalChamber, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' THEN 1 END) AS totalCity, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%' THEN 1 END) AS MulCnt, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%') THEN 1 END) AS MulCntChamber, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%') THEN 1 END) AS MulCntCity, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%' AND B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS MulCntChamberUN, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%' AND B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS MulCntCityUN, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%' THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCnt, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%') THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCntChamber, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%') THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCntCity, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%' AND B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCntChamberUN, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%' AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-RR-%' AND B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS NonMulCntCityUN, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL THEN 1 END) as unTouched, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL AND RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p') THEN 1 END) as unTouchedChamber, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL AND RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c') THEN 1 END) as unTouchedCity, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-MUL%') THEN 1 END) as unTouchedMul, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL AND LIST.LISTDESC NOT LIKE '%-MUL%') THEN 1 END) as unTouchedNonMul, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%' THEN 1 END) as reRunCnt, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%' AND B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) as reRunCntUN, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%') THEN 1 END) AS reRunCntChamber, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%') THEN 1 END) AS reRunCntCity, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'p' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%' AND B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS reRunCntChamberUN, " & _
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (RIGHT(PROJ.ProjCode,1) = 'c' AND LIST.LISTDESC LIKE '%-RR-%' AND B.BLXFLastUpdate IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS reRunCntCityUN " & _
      "FROM BLXF B INNER JOIN LIST ON B.BLXFLISTID = LIST.LISTID " & _
      "INNER JOIN BSST ON B.BLXFBSSTID = BSST.BSSTID " & _
      "INNER JOIN EMPL E ON LIST.LISTEMPLID = E.EMPLID " & _
      "INNER JOIN PROJ ON LIST.LISTPROJID = PROJ.PROJID " & _
      "WHERE (LIST.LISTAvailable = 1) AND (BSST.BSSTTerminalInd = 0) AND (PROJ.PROJPJSTID = 2) AND (E.EMPLStatus = 'y') " & _
      "GROUP BY E.EMPLDesc, E.EMPLID, E.EMPLSalesmanID " & _
      ") E " & _
      "ORDER BY " & theOrderBy
```

Comment: Have you considered sorting your table client side, there are loads of jQuery plugins which can do this, here's an example - http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Have not tried that yet was trying to keep it server side but if I cant get it working I may look into the client side sorting

Answer (score 0):

Because those two fields are computed columns before you can access them by their alias you would need to wrap them in a sub query.

```
SELECT E.[employeeName], E.[theTotal], E.[unTouched]
, (E.[theTotal] - E.[unTouched]) [theDifference]
FROM (
  SELECT E.employeeName,
  COUNT(B.ID) [theTotal],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN B.ID IS NULL THEN 1 END) [unTouched]
  FROM EMPL E
  INNER JOIN BUSINESS B ON E.SomeField = B.SomeField
  WHERE E.STATUS = 1
  GROUP BY E.employeeName
) E
ORDER BY E.[employeeName];
```

The `INNER JOIN` needs to join on some fields that form the relationship between the `EMPL` table and `BUSINESS` table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am getting an error: The multi-part identifier "EMPL.employeeName" could not be bound

Comment: @Loopy I just copied your query and wrapped it but realise that the `INNER JOIN` isn't right, should be `INNER JOIN BUSINESS ON EMPL.SomeField = BUSINESS.SomeField`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I edited my initial post to put in the entire query because maybe in my short example I am missing a key component. Let me know if you see anything, thanks!!

Comment: @Loopy probably the lack of alias for the tables have added `E` and `B` and referencing fields to them, see updated SQL.

Comment: I updated the query, same exact error - well more specifically it says: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "EMPL.EMPLDesc" could not be bound.". I think the problem is I have multiple tables I am joining and in the short example its just a simple 2 table join -- I have an updated query above

Comment: @Loopy That field isn't even in the query so whatever you are doing it's not this doing it. The reference to `EMPL.EMPLDesc` if you are modifying the above query should use the alias `E.EMPLDesc` as it won't know `EMPL` hence the `multi-part error`, remember the sub query isn't a real table just a sub query alias of `E` it won't know what `EMPL` is.